# What are the latest arguments for/against the existence of God?

Tags: theology, existence, debate

What are the newest or latest arguments for or against the [existence of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existence_of_God)?

What is the state of this debate? After proponents and critics have argued and responded to everything so far, what else is there to talk about? What are they stuck on?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "latest"? Most arguments on this subject have a very long history. (Also, just in passing, it would seem this question has largely become considerably less urgent for mainstream philosophy in the modern era. I might suggest a review of Existentialism, certain proponents of which essentially hold God's existence or inexistence to be effectively irrelevant to human life.)

Comment: One could consider asking such a question at a other sites that have theologically directions, namely skeptics.SE and judaism.SE (for very different reasons). I suspect you'll get more thoughtful responses from the latter site (it has more academic leanings).

Comment: There is an upcoming Christianity site too, but I'm not sure they will say they are "stuck on" anything... As for the question, I think the idea for this question is OK, but it is somewhat speculative as posed ("what are they stuck on?") so it's borderline.

Answer (score 5):

There is a recent philosophical novel entitled [36 Arguments for the Existence of God](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307378187) by philosopher Rebecca Goldstein (who happens to be married to Steven Pinker) which contains a catalog of 36 arguments (and the corresponding refutations).

Other than this, I can't think of any recent literature on the subject, which as you note, is rather well worn.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the conflict regarding the existence of God is and always will be stuck on the nature of **faith**, not on argumentation. No theories wholly prove or disprove the existence of God. Why then, you ask, isn't everyone an athiest? After all, we believe in things that are proven, not those that are merely *not disproven*. The answer is faith. It is ***by definition*** an impenetrable shield against all reason as it allows it's wielder to be confident in his or her beliefs *without evidence*. That means one can still believe in something without actually having any proof or following any standard of reasoning.

Because of this, whether or not arguments successfully prove or disprove the existence of God is irrelevant; in the end, people of strong faith will never be swayed, even as science continues to gobble up the realm of the unknown which was once only the dominion of God.

This is why there is still debate; This is what people are "stuck on".

Comment: `an impenetrable shield against all reason` `even as science continues to gobble up the realm of the unknown which was once only the dominion of God.` `This is what people are "stuck on".` Nice words, so true. +1

Comment: Which, by the way, is one reason that religious scholars and scientists alike have started cautioning against a ["god of the gaps"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_of_the_gaps). That is, attributing the as-yet-unexplained features of the natural world to God. Eventually, if a scientific explanation is found for those phenomena, what happens to God? It is almost as if we begin to define Her out of existence.